# ¿Cómo usar variable fuera de bloque?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una comparativa en JavaScript de un valor que me devuelve una promesa, el valor que recibo es un valor numérico y quiero cambiar a un **string** en dependencia del valor y usarlo posteriormente.

Éste es mi código:

```
const valor = 1;
if (valor==1){
  const nvovalor = 'Aqui cambio el valor';
}
```

Luego de hacer esto debo usar el **nvovalor** en un **div**:

```
$('#myhtml).html(nvovalor)
```

Ahora el problema que tengo es que debo hacer al menos 12 comparaciones antes de imprimir el valor en el **div**. ¿Alguna idea de como puedo desarrollarlo?

Actualmente estoy trabajando con jquery, todo mi codigo es asi:

```
async function mydata(){
  const tkn = await myContract.methods.TokenID(id).call();
  const category = tkn[0] // Aqui toma el valor de 1
  if (category == 1) {
    let category = 'my new data string';
  }
  ('#mydiv').html(category) // me muestra 1, necesito que me muestre "my new data string"   
}
```

Esa comparacion debo hacerla con varias subcategorias

Comment: Estas confundiendo java y javascript de manera muy fuerte, puesto que en javascript no hay tipado, si deseas cambiar un valor de string a int lo puedes hacer directamente, no tienes que pasar por conversiones ni declarar tipos, aparte... usar variable fuera de bloque??, pero si no hay ninguna variable en tu código que tenga un problema de bloques, es decir, ese código como lo tienes funcionaria bien si existiese el elemento html con id myhtml.

Comment: Entonces el problema es de java o de javascript??, recuerda, no son lo mismo, solo en java debes definir si van a ser numeros letras o demas cosas una variable... en javascript esto no es asi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto fue lo que dio resultado:

//cree una funcion que recibiera el valor y me retornara el string

```
 const category = 1; //valor que recibe la constante

 function cat(category){
            if (category == 1) {
                return 'My new string data';
            }
        }
//despues llamo a la funcion desde el div
$('#mydiv').html(cat(category)) // imprime My new string data
```